# UILabels vertical hugging priority

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, ios-autolayout

I have UICollectionViewCell with 2 UILabels that both can have 1 to N lines of text. I would like to use autolayout for calculation of cell height. I have set constraints for labels as follows:
[image: UICollectionViewCell]

When I run my app, cells are not displayed properly. Layout inspector says that my labels have ambiguous height. I've read quite a lot of possible solutions and tutorials how to achieve self sizing cells, but without any luck. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: You need add priority for label, increase horizontal hugging priority for any one label. Open errors it will guide you.

Comment: how is the width constrained?

Comment: Width of top label is constrained to the width of cell, there are 24pt from each side. Bottom label has >= 30pt space from label with red text.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the last label bottom constraint's priority to 749. That's it !!

[image]

Comment: Why change priority on this constraint? I want this constraint to be required. It should be always 8pt from bottom of cell. Thanks

Comment: if you this constraints set as required then multiline label will be clipped.

Comment: Hi, that doesn't solved my issue. I still got ambiguous heights :/